# How to update "background-color" property of certain class with each record in extjs

Tags: css, extjs, background-color

I am working in extjs. I want to show different records with different colors. I am loading store and retriving records in callback function

```
taskStore.load({
        url : URL_TASK,
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {
            if(success) {
                for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                        records[i].set('Cls', 'assignedTasksCls');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

For each record i am setting Cls= "assignedTasksCls", which i have defined as,

```
.assignedTasksCls {
     background-color: #51c063; 
    border: 1px solid #8cd191;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5);
    height: 90%;
    left: -6px;
    line-height: 7px;
    position: relative;
}
```

I want to change this class's background-color property as need to set different colors to differnt records. I can get this css via= records[i].getCls();
So how to update "background-color" of this class with each record?

Answer (score 1):

The way of changing the background-color is

via JQuery

```
 $("#YourSelector").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Via Extjs
suppost you have

```
<div id="div1">My Div 1</div>
```

then

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.get('div1').setStyle('color', 'red'); 
});
```

for Class way use

```
   records[i].addCls("assignedTasksCls");
   records[i].removeCls("assignedTasksCls")
```

nice example [from here](http://peterkellner.net/2013/08/29/being-smart-with-css-classes-and-extjs-4/)

also, I found good example might be usefull for your case, please [check from here](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/tPB8Z/)

Comment: thanx for reply sir..But i dont have such selectorId. I am setting cls as field in record. So currently record.set('assignedTasksCls') is properly setting cls. But i want to set different color to differnt record. So how to update that color instead of updating whole class?

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the following links,

- [extjs change grid cell background based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904432/extjs-change-grid-cell-background-based-on-value)
- [changing background colors of grid rows dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826523/changing-background-colors-of-grid-rows-dynamically-in-extjs-4-2-2)
- [Change background color of row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114496/change-background-color-of-row-extjs4)

Answer (score -1):

See [this example](http://extjs.eu/ext-examples/#grid-styling-rows), it does exactly what you need.